# How to set up setters and getters to pass the test cases. Ceasar Cipher type problem

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter

I need help clearing some test cases from a main method that was provided. I had to set up the class that has the setters and getters as well as the translation but I am getting stuck.

This is the class with the test cases.

```
 // This is the driver for the Saurian class
 // Use this website to compare with your translator:
 //  https://saurian.krystalarchive.com/
 // Game that Saurian originated from:
 //  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Fox_Adventures
 // http://starfox.wikia.com/wiki/Dino

 public class SaurianDriver
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     // create the Saurian object using the default constructor
     Saurian saur = new Saurian();

     // TEST #1
     // Test the English word "College"
     // It should translate to "Seccowo"
     saur.setEnglish("College");
     System.out.println(saur.getSaurian());

     if (saur.getSaurian().equals("Seccowo"))
        System.out.println("TEST #1 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #1 Failed!");

     System.out.println();


     // TEST #2
     // Test the English phrase: "Hello World!"
     // It should translate to "Xocce Nehct!"
     saur.setEnglish("Hello World!");
     System.out.println(saur.getSaurian());

     if (saur.getSaurian().equals("Xocce Nehct!"))
        System.out.println("TEST #2 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #2 Failed!");

     System.out.println();


     // TEST #3
     // Test the Saurian word "Faqqu"
     // It should translate to "Pizza"
     saur.setSaurian("Faqqu");
     System.out.println(saur.getEnglish());

     if (saur.getEnglish().equals("Pizza"))
        System.out.println("TEST #3 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #3 Failed!");

     System.out.println();


     // TEST #4
     // Test the Saurian phrase: "Kubadw faskihoj aj vid."
     // It should translate to "Taking pictures is fun."
     saur.setSaurian("Kubadw faskihoj aj vid.");
     System.out.println(saur.getEnglish());

     if (saur.getEnglish().equals("Taking pictures is fun."))
        System.out.println("TEST #4 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #4 Failed!");

     System.out.println();


     // TEST #5
     // Translate "De edo sud tovouk GENERAL SCALES!"
     // It should translate to "No one can defeat GENERAL SCALES!"
     saur.setSaurian("De edo sud tovouk");
     System.out.println(saur.getEnglish() +  " GENERAL SCALES!");

     if (saur.getEnglish().equals("No one can defeat"))
        System.out.println("TEST #5 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #5 Failed!");

     System.out.println();

     // TEST #6
     // Translate "Soccer is a way of life!"
     // It should translate to "Jessoh aj u nuo ev cavo!"
     saur.setEnglish("Soccer is a way of life!");
     System.out.println(saur.getSaurian());

     if (saur.getSaurian().equals("Jessoh aj u nuo ev cavo!"))
        System.out.println("TEST #6 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #6 Failed!");

     System.out.println();

     // TEST #7
     // Test the English word "College"
     // It should translate to "Seccowo"
     // create the Saurian object and initialize the data
     Saurian saur2 = new Saurian("College", true);  // true means 1st 
     parameter is in English
     System.out.println(saur2.getSaurian());

     if (saur2.getEnglish().equals("College") && saur2.getSaurian().equals("Seccowo"))
        System.out.println("TEST #7 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #7 Failed!");

     System.out.println();

     // TEST #8
     // Test the Saurian word "Faqqu"
     // It should translate to "Pizza"
     // create the Saurian object and initialize the data
     Saurian saur3 = new Saurian("Faqqu", false);   // false means 1st parameter is in Saurian
     System.out.println(saur3.getEnglish());

     if (saur3.getEnglish().equals("Pizza") && saur3.getSaurian().equals("Faqqu"))
        System.out.println("TEST #8 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #8 Failed!");

     System.out.println();

     // TEST #9
     // Test the English word "Hello World!"
     // It should translate to "Xocce Nehct!"
     // create the Saurian object and initialize the data
     Saurian saur4 = new Saurian("Hello World!", true); // true means 1st parameter is in English
     System.out.println(saur4.getSaurian());

     if (saur4.getEnglish().equals("Hello World!") && 
     saur4.getSaurian().equals("Xocce Nehct!"))
        System.out.println("TEST #9 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #9 Failed!");

     System.out.println();

     // TEST #10
     // Test the Saurian word "Kubadw faskihoj aj vid."
     // It should translate to "Taking pictures is fun."
     // create the Saurian object and initialize the data
     Saurian saur5 = new Saurian("Kubadw faskihoj aj vid.", false); // 
     false means 1st parameter is in Saurian
     System.out.println(saur5.getEnglish());

     if (saur5.getEnglish().equals("Taking pictures is fun.") && 
     saur5.getSaurian().equals("Kubadw faskihoj aj vid."))
        System.out.println("TEST #10 Passed!");
     else
        System.out.println("TEST #10 Failed!");

     System.out.println();

     // TEST #11
     // Test the toString()
     System.out.println(saur.toString());
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(saur2.toString());
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(saur3.toString());
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(saur4.toString());
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(saur5.toString());
     }
 }
```

This is the class with all of the methods.

```
// Programmer:
// Date:
// The Saurian class has the ability to translate English to Saurian
// and Saurian to English

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Saurian
{
    // data

    // constants used for translating
    // note M = M and m = m so M and m are not needed
    public static final Character[] ENGLISHARR = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    public static final Character[] SAURIANARR = {'U','R','S','T','O','V','W','X','A','Z','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','I','L','N','P','O','Q','u','r','s','t','o','v','w','x','a','z','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','i','l','n','p','o','q'};
    public static final int ARRLENGTH = ENGLISHARR.length;  // should be the same length for ENGLISHARR and SAURIANARR

    private String saurian = "";
    private String english = "";


    public Saurian()
    {
        english = "";
        saurian = "";

    }
    public Saurian(String phrase, Boolean which)
    {
        //If the string is in english the boolean will be stored as true and I will pass the phrase on to english as well
        if(which == true)
        {
            english = phrase;

            saurian = translateEngToSaur(phrase);
        }
        else
        {
            saurian = phrase;

            english = translateSaurToEng(phrase);
        }
    }


    public void setEnglish(String newEnglish)
    {
        english = newEnglish;
        //Just seeing what the output is
        System.out.println("This is newEnglish " + newEnglish);
    }

    public String getEnglish()
    {
        //Just seeing what the output is
        System.out.println("This is getEnglish   "+ english);
        return english;

    }

    public void setSaurian(String newSaurian)
    {

        saurian = newSaurian;
    }

    public String getSaurian()
    {
        //Just seeing what the output is
        System.out.println("This is getSaurian   "+ saurian);
        return this.saurian;
    }

    public String translateSaurToEng(String saurianToEnglish)
    {

        String word = saurianToEnglish;

        // String that will be used to store the word after it has been
        // translated and will be built using the for loops

        // For loop that loops as long as the input is Ex. "Hello World" is 11
        // characters long
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            // indexOfYellow should store the index number for which the letter in the string was located in the array.
            int indexOfYellow = Arrays.asList(ENGLISHARR).indexOf(word.charAt(i));

            // Should Check if the character at index i is present in ENGLISHARR then it will save it to saurianToEnglish
            if (indexOfYellow != -1)
            {
                saurian += SAURIANARR[indexOfYellow];

                // This is just here to see if the if statement passed
            }
            else
            {
                saurian += word.charAt(i);

                // This is just here to see if the if statement failed
            }
        }
        return saurian;
    }
    public String translateEngToSaur(String englishToSaurian)
    {

        String word = englishToSaurian;

        // String that will be used to store the word after it has been
        // translated and will be built using the for loops

        // For loop that loops as long as the input is Ex. "Hello World" is 11
        // characters long
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            // indexOfYellow should store the index number for which the letter in the string was located in the array.
            int indexOfYellow = Arrays.asList(SAURIANARR).indexOf(word.charAt(i));

            // Should Check if the character at index i is present in ENGLISHARR then it will save it to saurianToEnglish
            if (indexOfYellow != -1)
            {
                english += ENGLISHARR[indexOfYellow];

                // This is just here to see if the if statement passed
            }
            else
            {
                english += word.charAt(i);

                // This is just here to see if the if statement failed
            }
        }
        return english;
    }


}
```

I have tried to store a value inside of a getter method by changing

```
 public void translateSaurToEng(String saurianToEnglish)
```

and

```
 public void translateEngToSaur(String englishToSaurian)
```

into

```
 public String translateSaurToEng(String saurianToEnglish)

 public String translateEngToSaur(String englishToSaurian)
```

so that I can return a value and store it for later use.

I then did this

```
public String getSaurian()
{
    //Just seeing what the output is
    this.saurian = translateEngToSaur(english);

    return this.saurian;
}

public String getEnglish()
{
    this.english = translateSaurToEng(saurian);

    //Just seeing what the output is for english
    System.out.println("This is getEnglish   "+ english);

    return this.english;
}
```

but the method is incompatible because

```
 translateSaurToEng(saurian)
```

is void, that is why I changed it to

```
public String translateSaurToEng(String saurianToEnglish)
```

then tried to do it this way but it was not letting me because of an error.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm not understanding the point of your application. What is translateSaurToEng and translateEngToSaur supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close! The problem is actually in your setter methods. In addition to setting the passed String to one field, you should translate the passed String and set that translation to the other field.

i.e.

```
public void setSaurian(String newSaurian)
{
     //this is what you have now:
    saurian = newSaurian;

     //this is what you need to add:
    english = translateSaurToEnglish();
}
```

If you do this in both setter methods, then you getter methods should just be able to return their corresponding member without any other code.

```
public String getEnglish()
{
    //this is no longer necessary:
         //this.english = translateSaurToEng(saurian);

    //Just seeing what the output is for english
    System.out.println("This is getEnglish   "+ english);

    return this.english;
   }
```